# Jsoup is unable to fetch complete content from a webpage?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to fetch content from following page with JSOUP:

http://www.peshawarairport.com.pk/Schedule.aspx?Type=Arrival

But it does not fetch the whole page content and returns me just the content till  tag closes. The content it returns is following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"  lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"  lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9"  lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9"  lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><html class="no-js"  lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">        var _prum = { id: "5227f1fbabe53ddc1f000000" }; var PRUM_EPISODES = PRUM_EPISODES || {}; PRUM_EPISODES.q = []; PRUM_EPISODES.mark = function (b, a) { PRUM_EPISODES.q.push(["mark", b, a || new Date().getTime()]) }; PRUM_EPISODES.measure = function (b, a, b) { PRUM_EPISODES.q.push(["measure", b, a, b || new Date().getTime()]) }; PRUM_EPISODES.done = function (a) { PRUM_EPISODES.q.push(["done", a]) }; PRUM_EPISODES.mark("firstbyte"); (function () { var b = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; var a = document.createElement("script"); a.type = "text/javascript"; a.async = true; a.charset = "UTF-8"; a.src = "//rum-static.pingdom.net/prum.min.js"; b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b) })();</script>
    <link href="~/images/favicon.ico" rel="CAA Shortcut Icon"></link>
    <title>Bacha Khan International Airport, Peshawar | www.peshawarairport.com</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <!-- <meta name="p:domain_verify" content="297cb2c48faff5539c27d75f076408b8"/> -->

    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/system.base.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/system.messages.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/system.theme.css?nkrgyj");
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/comment.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_api/date9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/field.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/node.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/search.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/css/jiap-website/user.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/modules/contrib/workflow/workflow_admin_ui/workflow_admin_ui9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/modules/contrib/views/css/views9687.css?nkrgyj");
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/css/ctools9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/modules/contrib/panels/css/panels9687.css?nkrgyj");
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/themes/sfo/css/bootstrap-n-responsive.min9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/themes/sfo/css/base9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/themes/sfo/css/theme_flysfo9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/themes/sfo/css/flysfo_cn9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/themes/sfo/css/mobilestyle9687.css?nkrgyj");
        @import url("http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/themes/sfo/css/jplayer.sfo/jplayer.blue.monday9687.css?nkrgyj");
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/sites/all/themes/sfo/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        var switchTo5x = false;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        stLight.options({ publisher: "a574d78b-ed29-4436-b50d-0213b9613fe7", doNotHash: true, doNotCopy: true, hashAddressBar: true, offsetTop:
```

Although if I hit the same url using browser or any Rest Client I get the whole page html.

**Java code:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.peshawarairport.com.pk/Schedule.aspx?Type=Arrival").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36").maxBodySize(0).timeout(maxTimeout)
                    .get();
```

Comment: Works for me, the problem must be in code you haven't quoted.

Comment: But re your title: Yes, JSoup *can* fetch complete content from a webpage.

Comment: Your code works fine.  I read until `</html>` with `timeout=1000`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right, the problem was somewhere else and jsoup is working fine.I think I should delete this question :(

Comment: @user818455: No need to frown. :-) I'm glad you found the problem! But yes, the question probably won't help others in the future, unless you update it to describe what was wrong and then post an answer saying how you fixed it. That would be appropriate if you think someone else will make the same mistake. But deleting it is fine as well. Best,

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line="";
    while (br.readLine() != null) {
        line = line + br.readLine();
    }
    //System.out.println(line);

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line.replace("<!--","").replace("-->",""));
```

Try this to fetch content